# How do I use a json file as a DashboardBody in CloudFormation with Serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

To create a [CloudWatch Dashboard in CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloudwatch-dashboard.html), you must supply the [dashboard's source code as a stringified JSON rather than as a separate JSON structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloudwatch-dashboard.html#cfn-cloudwatch-dashboard-dashboardbody).

This is annoying because my JSON has to be escaped inside of a string literal within my `serverless.yml`:

```
...
resources:
  Resources:
    MyDashboard:
      Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
      Properties:
      DashboardName: My-Dashboard
      DashboardBody: "{\"widgets\": [...]}"
```

I tried using a file reference:

```
...
resources:
  Resources:
    MyDashboard:
      Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
      Properties:
      DashboardName: My-Dashboard
      DashboardBody: ${file(my-dashboard.json)}
```

but `serverless` inserts the content as part of the YAML structure, rather than as part of the JSON string:

```
...
resources:
  Resources:
    MyDashboard:
      Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
      Properties:
      DashboardName: My-Dashboard
      DashboardBody:
        Widgets:
          - ...
          - ...
```

Is there a way to `stringify` the JSON from `my-dashboard.json`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way `stringify` JSON directly within a [serverless variable](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/). However, you can reference an external `.js` file, and then `stringify` the `.json` file there:

`serverless.yml`:

```
...
resources:
  Resources:
    MyDashboard:
      Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
      Properties:
      DashboardName: My-Dashboard
      DashboardBody: ${file(my-dashboard-body.js):myDashboardBody}
```

`${file(my-dashboard-body.js):myDashboardBody}` is a [serverless variable reference](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#reference-variables-in-javascript-files). It means that we want to use the value from the `myDashboardBody` module of the `my-dashboard-body.js` file.

`my-dashboard-body.js`:

```
module.exports.myDashboardBody = (serverless) => {
 const fsPromises = require('fs').promises
 return fsPromises.readFile('my-dashboard-body.json', 'utf-8')
};
```

`my-dashboard-body.json`:

```
{
  "widgets": [
    ...
  ]
}
```